# Making QMessageBox InformativeText Bold and increase font size

Tags: c++, qt4, qmessagebox

In my qt C++ gui application, I have a QMessageBox with 3 buttons and some standard functionality. I want to decorate all these with stylesheets and fonts and what not.

I am successfully able to do the following -

> i. Set MessageBox background.
>
> ii. Set Button background.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox msgbox;
    msgbox.setInformativeText("YOLO");
    msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok|QMessageBox::No|QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgbox.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    msgbox.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox { background-image: url(:/res/bk.jpg) }");
    msgbox.button(QMessageBox::Ok)->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-image: url(:/res/green_bk.jpg) }");
    msgbox.button(QMessageBox::No)->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-image: url(:/res/red_bk.jpeg) }");
    msgbox.exec();
}
```

But I am stuck on how to set a font (type and size) to the InformativeText field, and also how to make it Bold. I have referred to the [InformativeText Properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#informativeText-prop) but I am unable to sort things out. Any ideas on how to achieve this ? Thanks.

As an added query, can I change the fonts (type and size) of buttons as well and set Bold Italics etc ?

**EDIT**

I did the following changes to my code, and the results are baffling,

```
QFont font;
font.setBold(true);
msgbox.setFont(font);
```

After doing this, my informationText has become bold, my cancel button has become bold. But the Ok and No buttons are normal (non-bold). If I remove the setStylesheets for the two buttons, only then are they becoming bold (which is useless, since I want background images).

Any ideas to have a synergy in all these ???

Comment: I shooting guesses: 1.- See about setTextFormat of QMessagebox; 2.- Use html tags in informativeText; 3.- Make your own

Comment: thanx for the response, i am not confident about the html thingey (point 2). and I cant make own (point 3). am a total noob. I am looking for something inline to your point 1. But unable to find any code segment.. I am really sad because of low rate of responses. Maybe qt is not much preferred now-a-days.

Comment: Making your own is like making a dialog in designer, there are tons of examples and the web. About how to use ui files in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for your problems.

```
QMessageBox msg(QMessageBox::Information,"Hey", "Dude", QMessageBox::Ok);

QFont font;
font.setBold(true);
msg.setFont(font);

msg.button(QMessageBox::Ok)->setFont(font);

msg.exec();
```